# android shared layout from library to app

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I am creating three apps that are almost the same except some changes in the assets and raw files between them.

So I wanted to create a library from the first one, that will contain all the logic and activity and all the layouts and resources, and then import this library to the other two apps, and only change the assets and raw files.

the problem is that when the layout from the library loads, it is loading the assets from the library itself, and not the assets of the main app.

I am sure that my design here is wrong then I would also appreciate if someone can explain to me what is the right way to share activities and layouts as libraries in android.

NOTE: I don't want to use flavors. I want to build it as a completely different projects.

cheers

Comment: diid you consider build varient [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: @hasanhasan yes, I Don't want to use flavors, I want to use it through libraries.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?

> _the problem is that when the layout from the library loads, it is loading the assets from the library itself, and not the assets of the main app._

I'm not sure what you mean. This is the set up I am imagining you would have:

`:library -> :appA`, `:library -> :appB`, `:library -> appC` (appA,B&C depend each on :library)

Comment: @SegunFamisa so for example in the library I want to have a method that runs on all the files inside the `assets` folder in the app, and not the `assets` folder in the library. and I want the activities in the app, to use the layout resources in the library.